# Почему функция возвращает undefined?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

У меня есть массив, каждое значение которого обозначает сторону света:

```
let array = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"];
```

Если **рядом** друг с другом стоят NORTH/SOUTH или EAST/WEST, то эти значения удаляются  (то же работает и для SOUTH/NORTH, и WEST/EAST). В данном случае функция должна вывести WEST, но вместо этого возвращается undefined. Кто-нибудь может объяснить, почему так происходит?

```js
let array = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"];
 
let obj = {
 "NORTH": 1,
 "SOUTH": -1,
 "WEST": 2,
 "EAST": -2
}

function dirReduc(arr) {
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (i == arr.length - 1) {
   return 1;
  } else if (obj[arr[i]] + obj[arr[i + 1]] == 0) {
   arr.splice(i, 2);
   dirReduc(arr);  
  }
 }
} 

console.log(dirReduc(array));
```

Comment: внутри `else if` отсутствует `return` перед вызовом `dirReduc(arr);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let array = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"];

let obj = {
  "NORTH": 1,
  "SOUTH": -1,
  "WEST": 2,
  "EAST": -2
}

function dirReduc(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i == arr.length - 1) {
      return arr[0]; // or return arr;
    } else if (obj[arr[i]] + obj[arr[i + 1]] == 0) {
      arr.splice(i, 2);
      return dirReduc(arr);
    }
  }
}

console.log(dirReduc(array));
```